# Itext7 error on embedded fonts when generating pdfa

Tags: java, fonts, itext7, pdfa

I am trying to generate a PDF-A but I get the following error when I try to set the font to the Paragraph :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.pdfa.exceptions.PdfAConformanceException: All the fonts must be embedded. This one is not: Courier
    at com.itextpdf.pdfa.checker.PdfA1Checker.checkFont(PdfA1Checker.java:305)
    at com.itextpdf.pdfa.PdfADocument.flushFonts(PdfADocument.java:282)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:968)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.close(Document.java:117)
    at testcreatepdfa.TestCreatePDFA.main(TestCreatePDFA.java:62)
C:\Users\UC9001309\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

In the normal pdf generation I used these commands to set the font to the paragraph :

```java
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.COURIER);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.setFont(font);
```

But in PDF-A I get the error about embed fonts.
Maybe because it is already incorporated?
Does anyone know which command to use for p.setFont without creating the font but using the font embedded ?

```java
package testcreatepdfa;

import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgramFactory;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.constants.StandardFonts;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfAConformanceLevel;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocumentInfo;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputIntent;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfString;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfViewerPreferences;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.pdfa.PdfADocument;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

/**
 * @author UC9001309
 */
public class TestCreatePDFA {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        PdfWriter   pdfWriter = new PdfWriter("C:\\Temp\\" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new java.util.Date()) + ".pdf");
          PdfADocument pdfA = new PdfADocument( pdfWriter,
        PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1B,
          new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "", "https://www.color.org",
            "sRGB2014", new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\UC9001309\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\GestionePdf\\sRGB2014.icc")));       
        //Document document = new Document(pdfA); 
          
        Document document = new Document(pdfA, PageSize.A4, false);
        pdfA.setTagged();
        pdfA.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("it-IT"));
        pdfA.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().setDisplayDocTitle(true));
        PdfDocumentInfo info = pdfA.getDocumentInfo();
        info.setTitle("TEST PdfA "); 
        System.out.println(FontProgramFactory.getRegisteredFontFamilies());
        System.out.println(FontProgramFactory.getRegisteredFonts());

        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.COURIER);

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.setFont(font);
        p.add("Prova pdfa");
        document.add(p);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You use Courier from the `StandardFonts`. In PDF 1.x a PDF viewer is expected to have a copy of each of these standard 14 fonts included, Thus, your `PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.COURIER)` returns a PDF font object that only references but not embeds the font in the PDF. The PDF/A standards, though, expect all fonts to be embedded as far as they are used in the document. Thus, your using that font like you do is incompatible with PDF/A generation. Instead use a font file you have available on your computer.

Comment: It is true that you are absolutely right, in fact, I place the solution I have adopted (which practically does what you said) and this is how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution adopted to solve the problem:

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfAConformanceLevel;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocumentInfo;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputIntent;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfString;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfViewerPreferences;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.pdfa.PdfADocument;
import com.itextpdf.pdfa.checker.PdfAChecker;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


/**
 *
 * @author UC9001309
 */
public class TestCreatePDFA {

public static final String courier = "C:\\Windows\\fonts\\couri.ttf";
public static final String times = "C:\\Windows\\fonts\\times.ttf";
public static final String helvetica = "C:\\Windows\\fonts\\helvetica.ttf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
         PdfWriter   pdfWriter = new PdfWriter("C:\\Temp\\" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new java.util.Date()) + ".pdf");
          PdfADocument pdfA = new PdfADocument( pdfWriter,PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1B,new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "", "https://www.color.org",
            "sRGB2014", new FileInputStream("C:\\Windows\\System32\\spool\\drivers\\color\\sRGB Color Space Profile.icm")));  
              
         
         PdfAChecker chk = null;
        
        Document document = new Document(pdfA, PageSize.A4, false);
        pdfA.setTagged();        
        pdfA.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("it-IT"));
        pdfA.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().setDisplayDocTitle(true));
        PdfDocumentInfo info = pdfA.getDocumentInfo();
        info.setTitle("TEST PdfA " ); 
        
        PdfFont font_h = PdfFontFactory.createFont(helvetica);
        PdfFont font_c = PdfFontFactory.createFont(courier);
        PdfFont font_t = PdfFontFactory.createFont(times);
        
         Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
         p.setFont(font_c);
         p.setItalic();
         p.add("Prova pdfa");
         
         Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
         p1.setFont(font_h);
      
         p1.add("Prova pdfa");
         
         Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph();
         p2.setFont(font_t);
      
         p2.add("Prova pdfa");
         
         document.add(p);
         document.add(p1);
         document.add(p2);
         document.close();
    }
    
}
```